# Disqus - Get the list of my forums

Tags: api, disqus, forums

Is there a way to get the list of my forums, using the Disqus API 3.0?
I have a working example using API 1.1, and the 'get_forum_list' call, but I can't find the equivalent in the 3.0 version.

I'd like to sync the comments of all my forums, without having to maintain their list, with my local DB, and if possible using the current version of their API.

Getting all comments, from all my forums all together would work as well, but the forums/listPosts call can be done per forum, or for all forums (not only mine, but the whole community :/).

Thanks for any help you can bring me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, we have an API call "users/ListForums" which will list all the forums that you currently administer. To look up by username, you'll just need to pass `user=username:your_disqus_username` as the argument. Here's the documentation for this API call: http://disqus.com/api/docs/users/listForums/

It's important to note a key difference between API 1.1 and 3.0, in that you don't need to store a forum ID number. API 3.0 makes extensive use of shortnames, which is the unique names you register with your site rather than an assigned ID number.

If you're trying to synchronize multiple forums with a single API call, you'll actually want to use "posts/List" which lets you pass multiple shortnames at once: http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/

Ryan
Community Support @ Disqus